# Estimating effective degrees of freedom of a time series (of circular data)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, degrees-of-freedom, circular-statistics

I have a $1 \times N$ vector, *x* of instantaneous phases (in radians).

To determine the 'systematicity'  or 'non-uniformity' of this set of phases, I use the formula (in MATLAB notation):

```
r=abs(sum(exp(1i*x))/N);
```

this gives me a value between $0$ and $1$.

To determine if the 'systematicity' of the phases is statistically significant, it is typical to use the Rayleigh test for non-uniformity of phases, whereby the test statistic is:

```
z = N*r^2;
```

and the p-value indicating probability of null hypothesis being true (i.e. uniform distribution of phases) is:

```
p=exp(-z);
```

in the case of consecutive phases values being independent, the above would be accurate.

However, my vector of instantaneous phases has substantial autocorrelation, so the above value for $z$ should be:

```
z=(effective-degrees-of-freedom)*r^2;
```

**Question**: how could I arrive at an estimate effective degrees of freedom of this vector, *x* (i.e. vector of instantaneous phases in radians)?